# Npm run build fails on live server with Next JS 13

Tags: next.js, build, path

I have a project in Next JS 13. My folder structure is as follows:

```
/components
/helpers
/pages
/public
/styles
jsconfig.json
next.config.js
```

In jsconfig.json I use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
}
```

So that I can work with paths in my pages directory and components directory like:

```
import Layout from 'helpers/layout';
```

When I run `npm run dev` locally it works perfectly. Als `npm run build` on my mac runs perfect.

However, when I try to deploy on a production server (`git pull` and then `npm install` and `npm run build`) using the same node version, I get the error:

```
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'helpers/layout'`
```

I can't seem to find any differences between my local environment and my production server, but I must be missing something. Anyone got any ideas where to look?